# How to make Subtract textbox value be smaller/equal to Price textbox value and show the Price in another textbox in Asp.net core C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Tools used Visual Studio 2019, Asp.net core 5.0 (.net 5.0)

I have 3 textboxes: Pricex, Subtractx and Sumx.

**What i want is if the Subtractx value gets bigger or equal to Price value, then Subtract = Price and Sum = Price.**

**If it is possible, can this be done directly in C#?**

Im trying this JS code but its not working

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        getSum();
    })
    $("#Subtractx").keyup(function () {
        getSum();
    })
    function getSum() {
        if ($("#Subtractx").val() >= $("#Pricex").val())
        {
            $("#Subtractx").val($("#Pricex").val());
            var sum = /*parseInt($("#Rows_Qty").val()) * */parseInt($("#Pricex").val()) - parseInt($("#Subtractx").val())
            $("#SumX").val(sum);
        }
        var sum = /*parseInt($("#Rows_Qty").val()) * */parseInt($("#Pricex").val()) - parseInt($("#Subtractx").val())
        $("#SumX").val(sum);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In compare why are you not using `pareInt`? Also what if they are floating point values? ` if pareInt($("#Subtractx").val()) >= pareInt($("#Pricex").val()))`

Comment: Is there something wrong with your code? The js code works fine for me.Or you can change your code to `var sum = ($("#Pricex").val() - $("#Subtractx").val()).toFixed(2);`

Comment: i don't know javascript but tried to adapt the code to my needs. It means that even before, the script could subtract without problem but when the subtract value surpasses the price value, the sum gets negative and i don't want this. I want the sum to be zero or positive and the subtract value to be zero or equal to price (not bigger). How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a working demo, you can check it.

```
<label>Price</label>
<input type="number" id="Pricex"/>
<label>Subtract</label>
<input type="number" id="Subtractx"/>
<label>Sum</label>
<input type="number" id="SumX"/>
@section Scripts
{ 
    <script>
        $(function () {
            getSum();
        })
        $("#Subtractx").keyup(function () {
            getSum();
        })
        function getSum() {
            var x = parseFloat($("#Subtractx").val());
            var y = parseFloat($("#Pricex").val());
            if (x >= y) {
                $("#Subtractx").val($("#Pricex").val());
                var z = parseFloat($("#Subtractx").val());
                var sum = (y - z).toFixed(2);
                $("#SumX").val(sum);
            }
            else {
                var sum = (y - x).toFixed(2)
                $("#SumX").val(sum);
            }
          
        }
    </script>
}
```

Test result:

[image]